# How to bypass grub rescue?

Tags: grub

I had dual boot with Windows 8 and Kali Linux. I deleted Kali Linux partition. Then restarted. It showed grub rescue.

**I don't have any live cd or usb.**

I tried following commands which was there in YouTube:

```
Set root=(hd0,msdos6)
Set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
Insmod normal
```

And when I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> after this, it shows `unknown filesystem`.

So, please help me to boot into the already installed Windows.

Comment: Actually i cant get into Windows.. As soon as i press power button, i get into grub rescue!

Comment: You won't be able to `insmod normal` (or any other module, like the useful `chain` or `ntldr`) unless you've kept the partition for `/boot`, which was where `normal.mod` was

Answer (score 2):

Use `bootsect` in Windows to overwrite the boot code on MBR, then grub rescue will be gone:

```
bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824948.aspx

Comment: If you can't boot into Windows you'll need to have a Windows installation CD or USB